# The meaning of "begin the journey by bucking yourself up with tabloids."

Tags: meaning

‘We’ll put that aside for the moment. I’m thinking of a case where what we’ll call anæmia of the brain was masked (I don’t say cured) by vibration. He couldn’t sleep, or thought he couldn’t, but a steamer voyage and the thump of the screw——’

‘A steamer? After what I’ve told you!’ Conroy almost shrieked. ‘I’d sooner . . . ’

‘Of course not a steamer in your case, but a long railway journey the next time you think it will trouble you. It sounds absurd, but——’

‘I’d try anything. I nearly have,’ Conroy sighed.

‘Nonsense! I’ve given you a tonic that will clear that notion from your head. Give the train a chance, and don’t **begin the journey by bucking yourself up with tabloids.** Take them along, but hold them in reserve—in reserve.’

This is from "In the Same Boat " by Rudyard Kipling.
https://www.kiplingsociety.co.uk/tale/in-the-same-boat.htm

I don't understand the meaning below---
---
--begin the journey by bucking yourself up with tabloids.
What are the tabloids?

I am glad if someone would kindly teach me.

Answer (score 3):

From [the full OED...](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/196821?rskey=3GrIsz&result=1#eid)

> **tabloid**
> *Any small medicinal or chemical tablet; a pill.* **Now rare.**

In modern English, *Keep your **travel sickness tablets** in reserve*.

Comment: For those who don't have access to the OED, the [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tabloid#Noun) has it too.

Comment: Wiktionary (like [urban dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/)) doesn't have much credibility as an "authoritative source" for English. As it happens, Wiktionary cites a (different) instance from Kipling for its usage example - but I think the OED reference is better because it at least makes the explicit point that it's a ***rare*** (effectively, ***obsolete***) usage. Which could be inferred from the fact that @Patrick below (presumably a perfectly competent native Anglophone) didn't know this outdated meaning.

Comment: Wiktionary is pretty good, often better than a random Google result, for instance. Certainly not as good as a dictionary made by professionals full-time, but often it has more information and more valid than can be found elsewhere. Anyway, our job is to now go and add the obsolete tag to that entry :)

Comment: I'm not sure I see the point of bringing up Wiktionary here. The intended meaning was obvious to me anyway, and I only included the link to OED as a courtesy (I assume no-one would accuse me of making up the definition, if I hadn't cited an "authoritative source"). Basically, this ***isn't*** a usage learners should need to concern themselves with, so it's not really important that they should be able to find a universally-accessible definition...

Comment: ...if a learner insists on trying to learn English from texts that are over a century old, then if a *modern* free-access online dictionary doesn't give a relevant definition, they should try searching Google Books for any usage causing problems. And specifically, searching Google Books for texts written before about 1975 will probably *only* find ***tabloid*** used with the ***tablet, lozenge*** sense.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed and precise answer and advice.

Answer (score -1):

Tabloids are certain newspapers--the "tabloid" paper size is larger than a magazine but smaller than a "full-sized" newspaper.

I take it that Kipling's character advises to go on a train ride with something to read, but not to make that your main activity on the train.